# Google Spreadsheets: How to change Cell value, looping through a provided List and record result

Tags: google-sheets

I have built a Stock tracking worksheet on Google Spreadsheets where if I enter XYZ symbol in a cell B1, the Spreadsheet will pull in google finance data (sometimes very slow), do a series of calculations and output an Yes/No in cell B18.

In another Tab, named data, I have a list of 20 stock ticker symbols in cells A1:A20.

I want to write a function to change cell B1 with the information from data!A1:A20, looping 20 times one row at a time. During this process, at each step if the output in B18 is an "Yes", then the function should record the corresponding B1 input on say column L, starting at L2.

Any help, pointers will be sincerely appreciated for this newbie.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. I also added code to build a menu to run it from. I added a Utilities.sleep in the main function (commented out) in case you calculations take a long time. You might need it.

```
function onOpen() {
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu(
    'Stocks', [ 
      { name: 'Check Stocks', functionName: 'Stocks' }, 
      ]);   
}

function Stocks() {
  ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
 var s= ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")// main sheet
 var s1=ss.getSheetByName("data")//sheet with stock list starting in column  A row 1
 var lr = ss.getSheetByName("data").getLastRow()//get the last row of stocks (can be more than 20)
  var stk=s1.getRange(1,1,lr-1,1).getValues()//get the stock symbols
  var newArray=[]//array of "yes" stocks
  for(i=0;i<stk.length;i++){
  // Utilities.sleep(2000)//might be needed if your calculation take a long  time
  var curSym=s.getRange(1,2,1,1).getValue()//B1 stock
  var z =stk[i][0]//stock from data list
 s.getRange(1,2,1,1).setValue(z)
 var yn=s.getRange(18,2,1,1).getValue()//yes or no from b18
  if(yn=="Yes"){//if yes add to newArray
    newArray.push([stk[i][0]])
  }}
 s.getRange(2,12,newArray.length,1).setValues(newArray)//list "yes" symbols in col L
 }
```

Let me know if you have any problems. I do a lot of stock stuff.